# How to get elements by index in this array?

Tags: java, xml, libgdx

I am creating an array from an XML list like this:

```
Array<Element> a = root.getChildrenByName("Element name");
```

I'm trying to get the XML data out by index but this is not working.

```
int result = a.get(i).getInt("attribute name"); //Does not change anything to the result.
int result = tiles.items[i].getInt("attribute name"); //Results in an error.
```

I tried casting it to a regular array[] but that does not work out either. When debugging the array i created from the xml file i can see the XML written at the bottom when hovering over the array, i am unable to see an actual "arraytree" in there.

```
[<element att="value"/>, <element att="value"/>, ...]
```

When i am trying to cast this array to a normal array[] or ArrayList or anything like that i'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader$Element;
```

Posting my complete code block and XML:

```
public static Tile[][] LoadMap(String file)
{
    Tile[][] map = new Tile[0][0];

    XmlReader xml = new XmlReader();
    try {
        Element root = xml.parse(Gdx.files.internal(file));
        int width = root.getInt("width");
        int height = root.getInt("height");
        map = new Tile[width][height];

        map = new Tile[width][height];

        for (XmlReader.Element l : root.getChildrenByName("layer"))
        {
            //Populate floor tiles
            if (l.getAttribute("name").equals("floor"))
            {
                Element data = l.getChildByName("data");                    
                Array<Element> tiles = data.getChildrenByName("tile");

                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        map[x][y] = new Tile();
                        map[x][y].tileTexture = tiles.get(x+y).getInt("gid");
                        //add properties since we know it uses the floor tileset.
                    }
                }
            }

            //Populate wall tiles
            else if (l.getAttribute("name").equals("wall"))
            {
                Element data = l.getChildByName("data");                    
                Array<Element> tiles = data.getChildrenByName("tile");

                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width;x++)
                    {
                        map[x][y].wallTexture = tiles.get(x+y).getInt("gid");
                        //add properties since we know it uses the wall tileset.
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
```

This runs fine, the if statements pass and each run every line of code will be read atleast once.

XML (might be more practical with a smaller sized map, this is just 10x10 though):

```
<map version="1.0" width="10" height="10" tilewidth="64" tileheight="32">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tilesheet01" tilewidth="66" tileheight="33">
  <image source="tilesheet01.png" width="462" height="495"/>
 </tileset>
 <tileset firstgid="106" name="wallsheet01" tilewidth="66" tileheight="140">
  <image source="wallsheet01.png" width="990" height="980"/>
  <tile id="0">
   <properties>
    <property name="eWall" value="0"/>
    <property name="nWall" value="1"/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
  <tile id="1">
   <properties>
    <property name="eWall" value="1"/>
    <property name="nWall" value="0"/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
  <tile id="2">
   <properties>
    <property name="eWall" value="1"/>
    <property name="nWall" value="1"/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="floor">
  <data>
   <tile gid="110"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="1"/>
   <tile gid="2"/>
   <tile gid="3"/>
   <tile gid="4"/>
   <tile gid="5"/>
   <tile gid="6"/>
   <tile gid="7"/>
   <tile gid="8"/>
   <tile gid="9"/>
   <tile gid="10"/>
   <tile gid="11"/>
  </data>
 </layer>
 <layer name="wall">
  <data>
   <tile gid="200"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="108"/>
   <tile gid="107"/>
   <tile gid="107"/>
   <tile gid="107"/>
   <tile gid="107"/>
   <tile gid="106"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="109"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="106"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="106"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="106"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="106"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="106"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="107"/>
   <tile gid="106"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="108"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="107"/>
   <tile gid="110"/>
   <tile gid="107"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Comment: What is Array? Do you mean ArrayList?

Comment: Hmmm, it comes from LibGDX. Let me try to to put the elements in another kind of list.

Comment: @Eran Having trouble doing that. Now that i search for libgdx array i can see people just doing array[i].something but that is not working for me.

Comment: What does "Does not change anything to the result" mean?

Comment: @JLRishe That it does not put anything in the result variable. If result==0 it stays 0 and if result == 99 it stays 99.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of a variable assignment that left the variable unchanged. Are you sure that line of code is running?

Comment: @JLRishe Yeah i'm breaking on it. If i edit my XML and change the numbers it remains unchanged.

Comment: @JLRishe Guess it's time to post my complete code. See for yourself, floor tiles always remain 1 and wall tiles always remain 0. I tried altering the first/last elements but it remains the same.

Comment: You read my mind. :) I was just about to ask for your code. This doesn't look right to me: `tiles.get(x+y).getInt("gid");` Shouldn't it be `tiles.get(x + y * width).getInt("gid");"`? With your current code, you will only read the first 20 tiles (most of them multiple times), so that explains why they're always 1 and 0.

Comment: Ups, delete this and forget that I was here. I actually never was here but thanks anyway :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error here:

```
tiles.get(x+y).getInt("gid");
```

This will cause it to go through the tile elements in this order:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
```

... and so on, up to element 19. Since all of the first 20 tiles are the same value except for the first one, this explains the behavior you're seeing. What it looks like you should be using is this:

```
tiles.get(x + y * width).getInt("gid");
```

Comment: Its funny I randomy altered my xml to see some change but it always remained the same. Perhaps I did not update my file all the time in eclipse, I hate that. Thanks though.